# Why is update-notifier.desktop scanning /proc/3782/fd without permission?

Tags: permissions, proc, update-notifier

Why is that, occasionally, `update-notifier` spits out a large number of "*Permission denied*" lines in `journalctl`?

```
Dec 04 08:55:32 ML systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Dec 04 08:55:56 ML pkexec[334886]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Dec 04 08:55:56 ML pkexec[334886]: jabowery: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/jabowery] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system-locked]
Dec 04 08:55:56 ML update-notifier.desktop[334889]: Cannot stat file /proc/3782/fd/4: Permission denied
Dec 04 08:55:56 ML update-notifier.desktop[334889]: Cannot stat file /proc/3782/fd/5: Permission denied
... about 300 lines...
Dec 04 08:55:56 ML update-notifier.desktop[334892]: Cannot stat file /proc/3782/fd/73: Permission denied
Dec 04 08:55:56 ML update-notifier.desktop[334892]: Cannot stat file /proc/3782/fd/74: Permission denied
Dec 04 08:55:56 ML update-notifier.desktop[334892]: Cannot stat file /proc/3782/fd/75: Permission denied
Dec 04 08:55:56 ML update-notifier.desktop[334892]: Cannot stat file /proc/3782/fd/1023: Permission denied
```